# Android Studio Can't Find tools.jar

Tags: java, android-studio, jar

In my searching I haven't found an answer to my issue. I have installed the JDK, and have even used Android Studio before on this machine. But now, when I try to run it, it is giving me the error:

"JDK Required: 'tools.jar' seems to be not in Studio classpath.
Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE."

I have checked my jdk's bin folder, and it doesn't appear to have a 'tools.jar' file in there, which seems weird to me, but looking around I found tools.jar in the lib folder. So, instead I added the libs folder to the JAVA_HOME variable as well. This didn't help either.

Can anyone explain to me how to get Android Studio to stop complaining? I want to just move the jar file over but feel like that is hackish. Everywhere I read leads me to believe that this should really just work as long as I have my JAVA_HOME variable set (which I do, by the way:  /home/andrew/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/:/home/andrew/jdk1.7.0_45/lib).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set JAVA_HOME to

```
/home/andrew/jdk1.7.0_45/
```

instead.

Comment: I'll accept the answer in a few minutes when Stack Overflow lets me.

Thanks!