# How do I fix the Android Studio error: "Cannot start uploading: The tools sdk jar could not be located." in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, android-studio

Recently, I have found an interest in Android coding, so I decided to download Android Studio. I decided that before I program my first application, I would first see if I could send a blank application to my developer account in order to test if it would send.

I made the project, then added a **Google Cloud Module**. I set the Module type as **App Engine Java Servlet Module**, and the client module as **app**. At first, the error was:

> "Error: Invalid App engine SDK Path."

I soon found, however, that the reason was because the *gradle appengine-java-sdk* was out of date, as it was on version 1.9.18. So, I installed the latest version, which is 1.9.24. So, I turned *Synchronize* with **build.gradle** configuration.

That fixed the error, so I went to *Build>Deploy Module to App Engine*. I selected my module, and set my cloud ID, then hit deploy. I then get a pop-up that states:

> "Cannot start uploading: The tools sdk jar could not be located."

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your JAVA_HOME global variable is pointing to your JDK location. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30177012/1819669) and this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16952990/1819669).

Comment: It is. Also, I am using Windows 7, so those aren't the methods in which you would go about setting it.